# Uniform Hölder continuity also holds for smaller exponent $c' \in (0,c]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity

Let $(S,\rho)$ and $(T,d)$ be metric spaces. Let $(S,\rho)$ be complete and $D\subseteq T$ be dense. Furthermore let $f:D\to S$ be uniformly Hölder continuous with exponent $c>0$ in the sense of

There exists a constant $K \in \mathbb R_+$ such that $$\rho(f(s),f(t))\leq K(d(s,t))^c,\ \ \ s,t\in D\ \mathrm{with}\ d(s,t)<1$$

> Why does this inequality also hold for every $c' \in (0,c]$?

Perhaps these help:

[link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68641/h%C3%B6lder-condition-for-different-exponent)
[link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318152/regarding-h%C3%B6lder-continuity)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $0\leq d<1$ and $c'<c$ we have $d^c<d^{c'}$. Think about how the graph of $x^a$ for $x\in [0,1]$ changes by changing $a$.